# What's wrong with my javascript? it keeps giving me an error in dreamweaver

Tags: javascript

At line 29(pixelScan) it shows me an error in dreamweaver i want to know what's wrong please help, i do not know what the error is, i am a noob at javascript so please help me:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var processes = {

  timerCallback: function() {
    if (this.myVideo.paused || this.myVideo.ended) {
      return;
    }
    this.videocontentPlayer.drawImage(this.myVideo, 0, 0, this.width, this.height);
    this.pixelScan();
    var self = this;
    setTimeout(function () {
      self.timerCallback();
      }, 0);
  },

  doLoad: function() {
    this.myVideo = document.getElementById("myVideo");
    this.videoPlayer = document.getElementById("videoPlayer");
    this.videocontentPlayer = this.videoPlayer.getContext("2d");
    this.videoPlayer2 = document.getElementById("videoPlayer2");
    this.videocontentPlayer2 = this.videoPlayer.getContext("2d");
    var self = this;
    this.myVideo.addEventListener("playing", function() {
      self.width = self.myVideo.videoWidth;
      self.height = self.myVideo.videoHeight;
      self.timerCallback();
    }, false);
  }

  pixelScan: function() {
    var frame = this.videocontentPlayer.getImageData(0, 0, this.width, this.height);
    for (var i = 0; i < frame.data.length; i++) {
      var r = frame.data[i];
      var g = frame.data[i+1];
      var b = frame.data[i+2];
      if (g > 120 && 2 > 50 && r < 165 && b < 60)
        frame.data[i + 3] = 0;
    }
    this.videocontentPlayer2.putImageData(frame, 0, 0);
    return;
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: Seriously!  You're not going to tell us what error occurs on what line of code?  This is like telling the mechanic over the phone: "My car is broken - what's wrong" and giving him no more information than that.  Look in the error console and your errors will be shown to you.

Comment: calm down dude i was editing it

Comment: Your question is still bad since you haven't explained which error you get.

Comment: i got the answer so i don't need your help anymore

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a missing comma seperator:

```
}, //here

pixelScan: function() {
```

Comment: Don't forget to close the question as off topic, since the problem is a typo.

Answer (score 1):

pixelScan isn't a function.

You're missing a comma separator before pixelScan.

Should be

```
this.myVideo.addEventListener("playing", function() {
        self.width = self.myVideo.videoWidth;
        self.height = self.myVideo.videoHeight;
        self.timerCallback();
        }, false);
    }
},
pixelScan: function() {
```